# Как можно задать количество шагов и начальное положение QScrollBar в graphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь сделать кастомный QScrollBar. Нарисовал различные картинки для подключения. Подключил и увидел что 'QScrollBar::handle:vertical' подключил две картинки. Погуглил и понял что это связанно с количеством шагов в  graphicsView. Но как мне задать их не понял. 
Как можно задать количество шагов и начальное положение QScrollBar в graphicsView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

кажется я мозг вывихнул пока читал :(
Смотрите в сторону наследуемых от QAbstractSlider

void    setMaximum(int), 
void    setMinimum(int),
void    setPageStep(int)

например:

```
QScrollBar* sb=ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar();
sb->setMaximum(1000); // сделаем скроллбар больше чем сцена
int pagestep = ui->graphicsView->scene()->height()/100; // можно вычислить размер шага исходя из сцены
//int pagestep = sb->maximum()/100; // или из длины скроллбара
// int pagestep = 5; // или фиксированный
sb->setPageStep(pagestep); // на столько пикселей будет постраничный скролл
sb->setSingleStep(1); // скролл кнопками будет по 1 пикселю
```

Comment: А как к ним обратиться ? ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar().????

Comment: дополнил ответ см. выше.